# Does size matter?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I noticed when I am diving and get fish, it tells me the size and if it is the biggest one I have caught of that fish. Does the size actually matter? Does it change the sale price or anything?

Comment: The price will not change, price and size are not related

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Size does not affect the price at all, only quality will alter the price (size seems have some influence to quality, though.)

Size however does matter in fishing contests, and when filling up your award book.